# What will be the SSIS Package Path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have Created a SSIS package and run it it worked fine then i deploy the project it is showing me the package in SSISDB

[image]

There I execute the package it works fine then i try to execute it through asp.net page using this code

```
    Application app = new Application();
    string path = @" I don't Know the package path";
        Package package = null;
        try
        {
             package = app.LoadPackage(path, null);
             package.Execute();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
```

kindly guide me how do i get the package path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packages live in a database, you can run them by calling a stored procedure to execute them, there's a good walkthrough [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2992/how-to-execute-an-integration-services-ssis-package-from-a-sql-server-stored-procedure/)